# nim two key table with generics

Tags: generics, hashtable, nim-lang

Trying to create a two key dictionary in Nim where where the value is a user specified type.

```
import Tables

type
  TwoKeyTable[T] = Table[string, Table[string, T]]

# initialize two key table
proc initTwoKeyTable[T](): TwoKeyTable[T] =
  result = initTable[string, Table[string, T]]()  

# check to see if keys k1 and k2 are in table
proc hasKeyPair[T](tkTable: TwoKeyTable[T], k1, k2: string): bool =
  result = false
  # check if first key is in table
  if not tkTable.hasKey(k1):
    return
  # check if second key in the tables
  if not tkTable[k1].hasKey(k2): # 1st error coming from here 
    return
  result = true

# add a value corresponding to the keys k1 and k2
proc addKeyPairValue[T](tkTable: var TwoKeyTable[T], k1, k2: string, val: T) =
  if not tkTable.hasKey(k1):
    tkTable[k1] = initTable[string, T]() # 2nd error coming from here
  tkTable[k1][k2] = val


var tkTable = initTwoKeyTable[int]()
echo tkTable.hasKeyPair("a", "b") # produces the 1st error
```

Which gave the following error:

```
lib/pure/collections/tables.nim(249, 38) Error: type mismatch: got (Table[system.string, system.int]) but expected 'int
```

I also have a problem with this.

```
var tkTable = initTwoKeyTable[int]()
tkTable.addKeyPairValue("a", "b", 1) # produces the 2nd error
```

Which gives the same error.

Comment: Use a tuple as a key.

Comment: I realize that is an option, but there are reasons I would like a two key table. I want to be able to select by the first key alone. Otherwise, if I wanted to get all values that have key1 = "a", I would need to go through all keys (tuples) and filter out keys that meet this criteria. It will eventually be a multikey table (possibly more than 2 keys), so being able to efficiently select based on the 1st n keys will be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a lot like a bug to me, I reported it: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/2722

As a workaround it works when `TwoKeyTable` is not generic:

```
import Tables

type
  TwoKeyTable = Table[string, Table[string, int]]

# initialize two key table
proc initTwoKeyTable(): TwoKeyTable =
  result = initTable[string, Table[string, int]]()

# check to see if keys k1 and k2 are in table
proc hasKeyPair(tkTable: TwoKeyTable, k1, k2: string): bool =
  result = false
  # check if first key is in table
  if not tkTable.hasKey(k1):
    return
  # check if second key in the tables
  if not tkTable[k1].hasKey(k2): # 1st error coming from here
    return
  result = true

# add a value corresponding to the keys k1 and k2
proc addKeyPairValue[T](tkTable: var TwoKeyTable, k1, k2: string, val: T) =
  if not tkTable.hasKey(k1):
    tkTable[k1] = initTable[string, T]() # 2nd error coming from here
  tkTable[k1][k2] = val


var tkTable = initTwoKeyTable()
echo tkTable.hasKeyPair("a", "b") # produces the 1st error
```